# MongoDB - Importing a db from local machine to MongoLabs

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I have a decent-sized database on my local machine that has a lot of important data that cannot be re-made easily (locally-tested user profile informatino, blog posts, that sorta thing). It's around 50mb in size.

I'm getting close to making my app live, and I want to bring this database to `MongoLabs`. I know how to connect to MongoLabs and set up a new database there, but I can't work out (if it's even possible) how to import a database from my local machine to `MongoLabs`, nor can I find any documentation discussing this.

Questions are:

1. Is this possible to do
2. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

If you open your database at mongolab.com and go to the Tools tab, you should see some helpful commands for migrating your data to your new database.

This support article also has more details:

https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20164381